# Set filter options on vue-good-table programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

How can one change the value that is displayed in the UI filter elements(input, dropdown etc)  in vue-good-table programmatically?

For example if I call:
`this.$set(this.table.columnsFilters, 'name', 'bob')`

I want the value in the HTML input field 'name' to display bob.

Unfortunatly the settting the values as i described above does not work

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want the value in the HTML input field 'name' to display bob. Instead what happens is my data is filtered by bob..."  Are you referring to like placeholder text?

Comment: Jakobovski - can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @MattOestreich I added clarification

Comment: So you want to programmatically change the current filter for a column?

Comment: @MattOestreich. Yes, but there is a difference between the filter and the value displayed in the UI, that is why I specifically mention the UI value. Usually the should be the same, but what I found is sometime the filter value is not identical to the value being displayed in UI.

Comment: Is my solution helpful or does it miss the mark?

Comment: @MattOestreich. I will get back to you on sunday I have not had time to check yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/475

Official recommended method of doing this for **version >= 2.17.5**:

```
this.$set(this.columns[foundIndex].filterOptions, 'filterValue', value);
```

If you want to have it done using $route query params:

```
for (var key in this.$route.query){
    var field = key;
    let foundIndex = this.columns.findIndex((c) => {
      return c.field == field
    });

    if (foundIndex !== -1 ){
      this.$set(this.columns[foundIndex].filterOptions, 'filterValue', this.$route.query[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Edit*** If you are using version `2.16.0` or above, you'll need to do this:

[**CodePen for *v2.16.0 +***](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/MNbKeV)

```
// v2.16.0 or higher
...
changeFilter(field, newFilter) {
      let newCols = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.columns));
      let found = newCols.find(c => {
        return c.field == field;
      });
      console.log(found);
      if (found) {
        if (found.hasOwnProperty("filterOptions")) {
            found.filterOptions.filterValue = newFilter;
            this.columns = newCols;
        } else {
          alert(`Column '${field}' does not have filtering configured!`);
        }
      } else {
        alert(`Field '${field}' does not exist!`);
      }
}
```

---

***Original Answer***

If I am understanding this correctly you want to set the filter for a field programmatially... Something like this should work.. Click the button to change the filter programamaticlly... If you change this line to any valid name, it will filter by that name... Change 'Bob' to a valid name...(like Dan)...

```
<button 
  style="width:200px;" 
  @click.stop="changeFilter('name', 'Bob')"
>Click To Change Name Filter</button>
```

[CodePen Mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/zQjEmK?editors=1010)

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "my-component",
  data: {
    columns: [
      {
        label: "Name",
        field: "name",
        filterOptions: {
          enabled: true, // enable filter for this column
          placeholder: "Filter Name", // placeholder for filter input
          filterValue: "", // initial populated value for this filter
          filterDropdownItems: [], // dropdown (with selected values) instead of text input
          filterFn: this.columnFilterFn, //custom filter function that
          trigger: "enter" //only trigger on enter not on keyup
        }
      },
      {
        label: "Age",
        field: "age",
        type: "number"
      },
      {
        label: "Created On",
        field: "createdAt",
        type: "date",
        dateInputFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        dateOutputFormat: "MMM Do YY"
      },
      {
        label: "Percent",
        field: "score",
        type: "percentage"
      }
    ],
    rows: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        age: 20,
        createdAt: "201-10-31:9: 35 am",
        score: 0.03343
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Jane",
        age: 24,
        createdAt: "2011-10-31",
        score: 0.03343
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Susan",
        age: 16,
        createdAt: "2011-10-30",
        score: 0.03343
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Bob",
        age: 55,
        createdAt: "2011-10-11",
        score: 0.03343
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Dan",
        age: 40,
        createdAt: "2011-10-21",
        score: 0.03343
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "John",
        age: 20,
        createdAt: "2011-10-31",
        score: 0.03343
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    clearFilter(field) {
      try {
        let found = this.columns.find((c) => {
          return c.field == field
        });
        found.filterOptions.filterValue = "";
      } catch {
        alert(`Unable to clear ${field} filter`)
      }
    },
    changeFilter(field, newFilter) {
      let found = this.columns.find((c) => {
        return c.field == field
      });
      if(found) {
        if(found.hasOwnProperty("filterOptions")) {
          if(found.filterOptions.hasOwnProperty("filterValue")) {
            found.filterOptions.filterValue = newFilter;
          } else {
            alert(`Column '${field}' does not have filterValue property!`)
          }          
        } else {
          alert(`Column '${field}' does not have filtering configured!`)
        }
      } else {
        alert(`Field '${field}' does not exist!`)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-good-table@2.15.3/dist/vue-good-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-good-table@2.12.2/dist/vue-good-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
      <button 
        style="width:200px;" 
        @click.stop="changeFilter('name', 'Bob')"
      >Click To Change Name Filter</button>
      <button 
        style="width:200px;" 
        @click.stop="clearFilter('name')"
      >Clear Name Filter</button>
    </div>
    <vue-good-table :columns="columns" :rows="rows" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working in vue-good-table 2.16.x, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @paul well thats annoying -- I tried a couple of things using the newer version, but to no avail. Perhaps it would be beneficial if you put in a issue on their GitHub repo? Possibly a bug on their end?

Comment: @paul - I have updated my answer with a working solution for v2.16.0+

Answer (score 0):

Vue cannot detect normal property additions (e.g. `this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi'`)

Therefore, using `this.$set(this.table.columnsFilters, 'name', 'bob')` instead of your code.

[More information about `$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-set)

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, here's a working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/aks9800/cyegzwL7/

Comment: @xaksis ... sigh.... https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/577#issuecomment-518043522 in 2.16.0+ the compare bug that you had in the code (which you originally repeatedly claimed had nothing to do with your code) was preventing this.... if you set the value to an empty string you do NOT have to use `$set`........only after you removed the bug, though.